# c++ application save and apply preference pattern (may be boost or something)

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

Typical situation: you have an application, that save and load preferences
(save and load handled by class `Config`).

Imagine there's such a preference for fonts of some GUI elements.

So we have

```
struct Font;
struct Config {
    const Font& getFontForSpecificGUIElement() const;

    //save to disk if Font changed

    void setFontForSpecificGUIElement(Font);
};
```

Whenever the font is changed I need to inform all instances of class `SpecificGUIElement` of that change.

How can achieve such notification functionality?

To keep `Config` simple I want to decouple that functionality. Besides, there will many properties like this (30-50 of them).

So in general I want:

1. Not require implementing virtual interfaces
2. I don't need thread safety
3. Convenient registration of event handlers
4. I need notification for new subscribed receivers, with last recent
   notification if were any (I mean, as in my example `Font` changed, and when new GUI elements subscribe on such event, they receive, event automatically triggered for them, and they receive last variant of `Font`)
5. Convenient registration of event type (I mean in item above
   we create some kind of value cache, so it should be simple add new one)

I suppose this is common enough requirements, so may be there already solution,
in popular C++ libraries, like boost ?

**Update:**
Why Qt not suitable for me. I see two approaches
with Qt, `QEvent` subsystem. But because of it is impossible
send event to unknown listeners it is no go. Why not signal/slots, first you need inherit `QObject`, second to implement (4), I have to create `MessageBus` class to cache last values, and adding new events starts require to much work:

add data field, add new signal, add function(X) to emit new signal, because of signal actually `protected` functions,
plus in (X) i need compare last value with new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this alsready exists in e.g.:

## Boost Signals2

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/signals2.html

There are many samples that should get you going.

Signals2 does offer thread safety, but I guess that doesn't harm.

Alternatively,

## Qt

Qt does have a signals/slots implementation, as do many other UI frameworks:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html

Comment: I update my question with description why Qt not suitable for my case. And I can not see how in boost signals2 I can implement (4)[caching of last changed value + 3 simple additional of new events at the same time], can you please describe?

Comment: `(4)[caching of last changed value + 3 simple additional of new events at the same time]` read as `(4)[caching of last changed value + (5) simple additional of new events at the same time]`

Comment: I implemented required functionality on top of boost signals2, details here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33640124/1244932